# Is there a string_view equivalent for other container types?

Tags: c++, string, iterator, string-view

A [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is:

> An object that can refer to a constant contiguous sequence of `char`-like objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero.
>
> A typical implementation holds only two members: a pointer to constant `CharT` and a size.

This allows for robust but lightweight inspection of a `string`. It's perfect for recursive functions that would otherwise be forced to work with `char*`s or `string::iterator`s to pare down a string.

My question is what about other containers? Why provide this only for `string`? What about other contiguous containers, such as `vector`, `map`, `queue`, etc?

Comment: `vector`, `array` and `T[N]` are covered by `gsl::span`, I think. And it's kinda debatable if `string_view` is really such a great idea.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'd actually just been looking at `gsl`! But tell me, why do you question the value of `string_view`?

Comment: If Ranges TS ever makes it to the Standard, it will provide a general and uniform convenient syntax to represent a shallow view into a piece of any container...

Comment: @aschepler Looks like probably as good of an answer. If you feel like typing it up I can accept.

Comment: @JonathanMee - There was great work done to add support types to the standard library, which would make dangling pointers and references that much rarer. And here comes a type which just... well... it feels like a step back in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string_view` is to a pair of iterators as a `std::string` is to a standard container of `char`.

In other words, we can use pairs of iterators (or in future, a standard *range* object) to represent views into standard containers.

The string-view provides extra, string-like functions that mostly parallel the extra, string-like functions that are part of `std::string`.  For other containers, the equivalent operations are generally constructed from standard `<algorithm>` functions.